# Do accidental clock presses get counted with DGT clocks connected to DGT boards?

Tags: fide, time-control, chess-clocks

I have played many games with DGT 2010, DGT 2000 clocks and they cannot be connected to DGT boards as far as I know. Also there is a button to know the number of moves played (rather clock presses) so even accidental presses are counted.

Clocks such as DGT XL, DGT 3000 can be connected to DGT boards (there is a port). I have played very little games on those but I assume there is a button to check the number of moves there as well.

My Question is when a clock is connected to a DGT Board will the accidental moves get counted there as well? Since the board will show the actual number of moves in broadcast does it give the same number in the clock?

Or is it something completely different?

Comment: not really sure but i guess the arbiter would need to be informed and he would probably adjust the clock

Comment: @brekker is it possible to adjust the move count in the clock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clock is programmed in a way it does not read number of moves from the board so it will count it as additional move.

The only obvious issue with this is when you have additional time per move - it will add extra time that should be retracted.